# Configuring Serilog to write to Slack via app.config

Tags: serilog

I've created an application that I want to get logging to Slack for a particular purpose. I've already confirmed that it is working logging to a RollingFile and to Seq. I've added in serilog.sinks.slackclient and the application runs, and logs, but nothing shows up in my Slack channel.

Can someone verify whether there is an issue with my config?

from app.config (obviously xxx, yyy, zzz are substituded for key values.):

```
<add key="serilog:minimum-level" value="Debug" />
<!--<add key="serilog:using:RollingFile" value="Serilog.Sinks.RollingFile" />-->
<add key="serilog:using:Slack" value="Serilog.Sinks.Slack" />
<add key="serilog:write-to:Slack" value="https://hooks.slack.com/services/xxx/yyy/zzz" />
<add key="serilog:write-to:Seq.serverUrl" value="http://localhost:5341/" />
<add key="serilog:write-to:RollingFile.pathFormat" value="C:\Logs\Serilog\Test-{Date}.txt" />
<add key="serilog:write-to:RollingFile.retainedFileCountLimit" value="10" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parameter name `webhookUrl` is missing out of the `write-to` directive:

```
<add key="serilog:write-to:Slack.webhookUrl"
     value="https://hooks.slack.com/services/xxx/yyy/zzz" />
```

Comment: Thanks, yes, I worked it out before checking back here, but this is 100% correct.